# Image icon for waiting after a button is pressed

Tags: android, onclick

I have an application that when a user presses a button, can view images frow web. Those other screens are in other activities. Because many images are many kbs, and it takes some time to load, I need something that will inform the user, that he has pressed the button and must waits. I tried using a spinner but i couldn'tmake it work for my xml, so can you suggest me anything else? Many android apps just have a black screen until the final view is loaded, or for example make the button change backgrounf color suggesting that the user has pressed it and must wait. And where in the code must I place it?

Here is my code.

```
b4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View l) {
                    /*ParnassosTheme();*/
                    Intent i = new IntentScreen.this,OtherScreen.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("id", id);
                    i.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
            });
```

and my other screen activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...do things...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do loading task show a progress dialog in the beginning of the task and dismiss it when work is done. Note: it works fine but onCreateDialog() is already deprecated [info here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateDialog%28int,%20android.os.Bundle%29). If you targeting SDK 11+ consider to use DialogFragment instead [read here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

```
public class OtherScreen extends Activity{
    private static final int LOADING_DIALOG_KEY = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // initialization

        // show loading dialog
        showDialog(LOADING_DIALOG_KEY);

        new LoadDataTask().execute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){

        ProgressDialog dialog = null;

        if (id == LOADING_DIALOG_KEY){

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setTitle("Dialog title");
            dialog.setMessage("Data loading...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
        }

        return dialog;
    }

    private final class LoadDataTask extends 
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            // do work here
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            dismissDialog(LOADING_DIALOG_KEY); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok i will try it and i will post. What do you mean by this: "Note: it works fine but onCreateDialog() is already deprecated info here.". And should I write anything on the initialitation section ?

Comment: by deprecated Google means better don't use it, because it is not supported anymore and in time (3 years IIRC) it will be removed from SDK. In initialization section you usually initialize activity's components. This section is up to you, nothing extra there to make ProgressDialog work.

Comment: Ok i tried this and it doesn'e change anything. if i remove the  dismissdialogbox it loads for ever.So  thnk that  have placed it in a wrong place. Where should I? After everything finishes?

Comment: Okay, sorry about that, code was wrong. I tried to simplify. ProgresDialog can't run in the same thread where work should be done. See edited answer. I tested it this time.